# Can I use assign to duplicate an object of objects?

Tags: delphi, clone

I have an object that inherits in 3rd degree from TPersistent and I want to clone it using the [Assign](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TPersistent_Assign.html) procedure.

```
MyFirstObj := GrandSonOfPersistent.Create();
//I modify the objects inside MyFirstObj
MySecondObj := GrandSonOfPersistent.Create();
MySecondObj.Assign(MyFirstObject);
```

How can I check it worked?
Does it work when the objects have many other objects?

I am trying to clone an object, is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: It would seem to me you could test this yourself in about two seconds, using the exact same code you posted. Add a couple more lines of code testing the values of something in `MySecondObj` that were modified in `MyFirstObj` and see if they're the same or different. You should learn to try things yourself first before just posting a question or asking someone. Experimentation is how we learn, and I personally learn things faster by actually trying to do them than I do when reading about them. Try it, and then ask questions afterward. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Assign` is a virtual method.  Any descendent classes that inherit from `TPersistent` should override `Assign` to handle deep copying of any new members added on top of the base class.  If your classes do not override `Assign` to handle these deep copies then using `Assign` to make such a copy will not be successful.  The base implementation of `Assign` calls `AssignTo` which attempts to use the source object's implementation to perform the copy.  If neither source nor destination object can handle the copy then an exception is raised.

See : [The Documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Classes.TPersistent.Assign)

For Example:

```
unit SomeUnit;

 interface

 uses Classes;

 type
   TMyPersistent = class(TPersistent)
   private
     FField: string;         
   public
     property Field: string read FField write FField;
     procedure Assign (APersistent: TPersistent) ; override;
   end;

 implementation

 procedure TMyPersistent.Assign(APersistent: TPersistent) ;
 begin        
    if APersistent is TMyPersistent then
      Field := TMyPersistent(APersistent).Field          
    else         
      inherited Assign (APersistent);
 end;

end.
```

Note that any class inheriting from `TPersistent` should only call `inherited` if it cannot handle the `Assign` call.  A descendent class, however, should always call inherited since the parent may also have actions to perform and, if not, will handle passing calling the base `inherited` :

```
type
  TMyOtherPersistent = class(TMyPersistent)
  private
    FField2: string;         
  public
    property Field2: string read FField2 write FField2;
    procedure Assign (APersistent: TPersistent) ; override;
  end;

implementation

procedure TMyPersistent.Assign(APersistent: TPersistent) ;
begin 
  if APersistent is TMyOtherPersistent then
    Field2 := TMyOtherPersistent(APersistent).Field2;     
  inherited Assign (APersistent);  
end;
```

In this example I've shown strings.  For object members you would either need to use their `Assign` methods or perform the copy in some other way.

Comment: In an overriden `Assign()`, you should not assign a default value to fields when passed an unknown source object. That is not standard practice.  If `Assign()` does not recognize the object, `TPersistent` passes the object to `AssignTo()`.  If `AssignTo()` does not recognize the object, then an exception is raised, and the original object being assigned to has not been modified at all. That is the expected behavior.