# How to copy data from one class into another class

Tags: class, delphi

how to copy data from one class into a second class using operator overloading with DELPHI ?

my dummy app goes like this :

```
type
  TClass_A = class
    a: String;
  end;
  TClass_B = class(TClass_A)
    b: String;
  end;

implementation    

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  a: TClass_A;
  b: TClass_B;
begin
  a := TClass_A.Create;
  b := TClass_B.create;

  b := a;  // <<-- What code should be here? Can I overload := operator?
end;
```

Comment: You can do this easily at the cost of using RTTI.

Answer (score 5):

The assignment operator cannot be overloaded in Delphi.

You will need to introduce a method to perform the copying. An example of how this might be done is `TPersistent.Assign`. It would be perfectly reasonable for you to derive from `TPersistent` and override the virtual  `Assign` method to implement the desired functionality.

Comment: what is the best programming approach for this task ?  not Operator overloading ?

Comment: Well, operator overloading is not an option as I mentioned. So the  remaining option is to introduce a method.

Comment: add a new mthode for class B , I can write the code myself.  should this be better part of a class helper  ?

Comment: Use class helpers when you cannot extend the class yourself. If these are your classes, don't use helpers.

Comment: TPersistent.Assign , can you extend the given sample code ?

Comment: Some examples here http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/memento/delphi/1 and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23163655/can-i-use-assign-to-duplicate-an-object-of-objects

Answer (score 3):

Here is a small example of how to do this with new style RTTI (D2010 and higher).
Please note that this is a very basic example which only copies fields (not properties) and works best with basic classes (do not use this with TComponent), the fields in the destination object must be the same type. FYI, there are [better examples](http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/object-cloning-using-rtti/) out there :)

```
uses 
  Rtti,...

function CopyObject(const FromObj, ToObj: TObject): Boolean;

var
  Ctx         : TRTTIContext;
  FromObjType : TRttiType;
  ToObjType   : TRttiType;
  FromField   : TRttiField;
  ToField     : TRttiField;

begin
 Result := False;
 FromObjType := Ctx.GetType(FromObj.ClassInfo);
 ToObjType := Ctx.GetType(ToObj.ClassInfo);
 for FromField in FromObjType.GetFields do
  begin
   ToField := ToObjType.GetField(FromField.Name);
   if Assigned(ToField) then
    begin
     if ToField.FieldType = FromField.FieldType then
      ToField.SetValue(ToObj, FromField.GetValue(FromObj));
     Result := True;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This allows me to copy a `TListBox` to a `TTimer`. I'm not sure that's such a great idea. Also, how does it treat members that are References? Shallow copy? Is that ideal?

Comment: like I said in my answer, it's a very basic example and is best used for PODO's (or DTO's) not for components. FYI, this answer doesn't answer to OP's question as the field names do not match...